# SSRS 2008 use different queries based on parameter value

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ibm-midrange

I have 2 Dataset queries and a parameter called 'database'

If the value for 'database' is 'abc', it should use the statement below

```
select * from abc.item
```

Meanwhile, if the value for 'database' is 'cba', it should use this statement

```
select * from cba.item
```

Initially, I tried passing in the parameter like this

```
 select * from ?.item
```

Of course, that didn't work.

I am using ODBC connection to an iSeries

Comment: Can't you add a IF condition? based on parameter value change the query. Or you can add a Dynamic query, and you can change the tablename based on parameter.

Comment: I did tried something like IIF(Parameter!database.Value = 'abc', "select * from abc.item")
But it gave me a query error

Comment: Try this: IIF(Parameter!database.Value = 'abc',
    "select * from abc.item",
     "select * from cba.item"
)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the returned columns are the same for abc and cba?

You have to dynamically build your query:

```
declare @param as varchar(25)
declare @sql as varchar(2000)

set @param = 'abc'
set @sql = 'select * from ' + @param + '.item'

exec (@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also create a common data set for both by writing an expression for connection String

Refer to url http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2011/06/dynamic-connection-string-in-sql-server.html